# Derivation of reversible flow work for open systems

Tags: thermodynamics, work, flow, reversibility

In derivation of steady reversible flow work, what sort of model are we considering, when we write the differential form of first law as $$\delta w=\delta q- dh-vdv - gdz $$
for one inflow and one outflow. I read somewhere that we consider a differential system that causes the system change but not very clear about it. Also we write $Tds = \delta q_{rev}$ from the 2nd law.  In flow systems usually heat input and output occurs at different temperatures so in what sense are we applying the 2 nd law here. Can someone help me with a rigorous proof for an open finitely extended system where the heat interactions are occuring at diffrent temperatures?
Thank you

Comment: Get yourself a copy of Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al.  All that you are looking for is in there.  Also, I think that this book may be available online.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the contribution of axial heat conduction in the entering and exiting streams is neglected, and only convection of entropy by these streams is included in the open system versions of the 2nd law.  So for steady state, with a single inlet and outlet stream, the open system version of the 1st law would read $$\sum_i{\dot{Q_i}}-\dot{W_S}=\dot{m}\Delta \left(h+\frac{v^2}{2}+gz\right)$$where $\dot{Q_i}$ is the rate of heat flow from the i'th heat reservoir in contact with the control volume at its boundary, $\dot{W_S}$ is the rate of doing shaft work on the surroundings, and the $\Delta$ refers to the change between the inlet and outlet streams. And the open system version of the 2nd law would read $$\sum_i{\frac{\dot{Q_i}}{T_{Bi}}}+\dot{\sigma}=\dot{m}\Delta s$$where $T_{Bi}$ is the temperature of the i'th heat reservoir in contact with the control volume at its boundary and $\dot{\sigma}$ is the rate of entropy generation within the control volume.

For the special case where we use a single constant temperature reservoir at the same temperature T as that of our inlet flow stream and where we allow the residence time in the control volume be sufficient such that the outlet stream is also at temperature T, these equations reduce to:$$\dot{Q}-\dot{W_S}=\dot{m}\Delta \left(h+\frac{v^2}{2}+gz\right)$$and$$\frac{\dot{Q}}{T}+\dot{\sigma}=\dot{m}\Delta s$$From this last equation, we have $$\dot{Q}=\dot{m}T\Delta s-T\dot{\sigma}$$Subtracting this from our 1st law equation then yields:  $$-\dot{W_S}=\dot{m}\Delta \left(h-Ts+\frac{v^2}{2}+gz\right)+T\dot{\sigma}$$$$=\dot{m}\Delta \left(g+\frac{v^2}{2}+gz\right)+T\dot{\sigma}$$where g is the free energy per mole.